# How to make scrollable tbody with sticky thead and tfoot

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table with sticky header and footer, and a tbody in between that scrolls, and importantly, the scrollbar must only be on the tbody, not the thead or tfoot (this is what the design calls for).

I have tried the following things:

1. My first attempt was to add a wrapper around the table and put the height and overflow on that. That mostly works except the scroll bar extends to the header and footer, which I do not want.
2. I have seen someone use `display:grid` and put a `display:contents` on the thead, tbody, and tr's in order for the th and tds to become the grid elements. I slightly modified that to use subgrids. I made the children of the parent grid also grids with `grid-template-columns:subgrid` and that seems to work except that the footer is pushed down by the overflown tbody.
3. I have seen some people say to make tbody `display:block`, but I can't get that to work, it just shoves the whole tbody into the first column.

I know I can do this with just divs and separate headers, body and footer components, but I would prefer to have it be a table as it seems more fitting to have table data in a semantic table (though if this is not possible, then that may just be the way to go).

```css
div {
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tfoot {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
 
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
 
thead, tbody, tfoot, tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
 
tbody {
  max-height: 128px;
  overflow: auto;
}
 
tfoot {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 128px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with the grid is a clever one, but instead of `max-height: 128px`, try `grid-template-rows: 1fr fit-content(128px) 1fr`:

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr fit-content(128px) 1fr;
}
 
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
 
thead, tbody, tfoot, tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
 
tbody {
  overflow: auto;
}
 
tfoot {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th><th>HEAD</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td><td>FOOT</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice. Got the grid idea from here https://adamlynch.com/flexible-data-tables-with-css-grid/. So this is a bit closer to what I want, except this makes the tbody fixed height of 128px. If there are few rows, they expand in height. I need it to be a max height of 128px.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you can use the [fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content_function) function, so you'd have `grid-template-rows: 1fr fit-content(128px) 1fr`

Comment: Ahh, perfection. Thanks!